# Write Julia struct to a C++ struct

Tags: c++, julia

For the following Julia code:

```
mutable struct MutationWeights
    mutate_constant::Float64
    optimize::Float64
end

const mutations = [fieldnames(MutationWeights)...]

@generated function MutationWeights(;
    mutate_constant=0.048,
    optimize=0.0,
)
    return :(MutationWeights($(mutations...)))
end

"""Convert MutationWeights to a vector."""
@generated function Base.convert(
    ::Type{Vector}, weightings::MutationWeights
)::Vector{Float64}
    fields = [:(weightings.$(mut)) for mut in mutations]
    return :([$(fields...)])
end
```

I wrote the following C++ alternative:

```
struct MutationWeights {
    float mutate_constant = 0.048;
    float optimize = 0.0;
};

const auto mutations = std::vector<std::string>{"mutate_constant", "optimize"};

template <typename... Args>
MutationWeights createMutationWeights(Args&&... args) {
    return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

std::vector<double> convertMutationWeightsToVector(const MutationWeights& weightings) {
    return {weightings.mutate_constant,
            weightings.optimize};
}
```

Is this the most sensible way of doing it, or would you suggest something different?

Comment: Hope my edit describes what your code is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Precision

`float` is usually a 32-bit floating point type. Perhaps you meant `double`? With C++23, you can use [`std::float64_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/floating-point).

### Aggregates

There is [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) that removes the need for `createMutationWeights`. Note that if narrowing conversion should be allowed, then `createMutationWeights` does not help with it.

### (Implicit) conversion functions

If the conversion into `std::vector<double>` is often needed, I would implement a conversion function and make it `explicit` (will require a cast like `static_cast` to be used) if needed.

```cpp
struct MutationWeights {
    float mutate_constant = 0.048;
    float optimize = 0.0;

    operator std::vector<double>() {
        return { mutate_constant, optimize };    
    }
};
```

### Reconsider the interface

I would recommend returning `std::span<float>` or even `std::span<float, 2>` (i.e. statically sized). One could also try `std::array<float, 2>` to avoid some lifetime issues.

Comment: Not that important but maybe you want to remove `weightings` from your vector implementation.

Comment: @dearn44, thanks, fixed now.